# Redux - How to extract the same business logic from three different reducers?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have three different reducers doing different things but at the end they all change a property in the slice object being passed on which is common to all of them. The part that is common is where it unregisters an element by removing a property and a reference in an array.

I wonder what the best practice is to extract the repeated code into a separate method. I can extract it to a helper function but for that I'd like to create a copy of the slice instead of mutating it directly, I don't own the project so I don't have lodash available as of now, so that's another hurdle.

A second option would be to keep the repeated code which goes against the DRY principle. Third, I could also create a function within the same file that does the job, which is not much difference from doing it in a helper.

What is the best practice here? I really don't think that keeping the repeated code is a good idea, but I also don't want to create a function that mutates the slice within it However, I don't have lodash available now for a deep copy so I wonder what I could do here.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely extract helper methods that can be called in reducers.

Assuming you're using Redux Toolkit and `createSlice`, you *can* write those helper functions as "mutating" update logic, and as long as you call them inside of `createSlice`, it's safe to use them that way, such as:

```js
function addSomeItem(state, item) {
  state.items.push(item);
}

// later
createSlice({
  name: "fruits",
  initialState: {items: []},
  reducers: {
    fruitAdded(state, action) {
      addSomeItem(state, action.payload);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but would you say that it's a good practice to change the state in a helper function?

Comment: "Yes", In that it _is_ a good practice to write "mutating" update code in a Redux Toolkit + Immer-powered reducer. It's the same code, and it's ultimately running inside of Immer regardless of whether it's inline inside of `createSlice`, or defined as a separate function.

Comment: @markerikson About this: "it's ultimately running inside of Immer regardless of whether it's inline inside of createSlice, or defined as a separate function" 

Do you have a link to the Immer's doc  or somewhere we can verify that described behavior?

Comment: Uh... not really sure what you're asking here. Immer's docs are at https://immerjs.github.io/immer/ , but what actually matters is that we wrote `createSlice/createReducer`, and they _always_ call Immer inside when handling the action: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/v1.8.4/packages/toolkit/src/createReducer.ts#L280-L282